# Wrong result in a determinant calculation using int data type in C

Tags: c, matrix, turbo-c, determinants

i want to know

**why is not possible to calculate all this using `int` data type?**

So, im trying to calculate triangle area using determinants in C, im using **turbo C 2.0** (i know is old), im getting a calculation inaccuracy when i use `int` data type, dont really know why, heres the code im using to calculate determinants

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int Area(int ax, int ay, int bx, int by, int cx, int cy)
{
    return ax * by - ay * bx + bx * cy - by * cx + cx * ay - cy * ax;
}

int main()
{
    int ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy;

    ax = 548;
    ay = 125;
    bx = 544;
    by = 344;
    cx = 68;
    cy = 209;

    clrscr();
    printf("%d", Area(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy));

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

using `int` data type it returns `-26288` when it should be `104787`.

i know this returns the `area * 2` and it can be negative, but thats not the problem here, since im using it for a convex hull algorithm.

`int` data type in my system is `16 bits` so i know i can store `2^16` numbers, i thought it could be a max `int` error but i tried using `long int` as well which is `32 bits` long, it didnt work, it only works when i use floating point data types such as `double` or `float` like so:

```
float Area(float ax, float ay, float bx, float by, float cx, float cy)
{
    return ax * by - ay * bx + bx * cy - by * cx + cx * ay - cy * ax;
}
```

with this i get the right answer, **but** the question i have is, again,

**why is not possible to calculate all this using `int` data type?**

am i using `int` in a wrong way?

*Thank you!*

Comment: `104787` exceeds the limit of 16-bit integer `32767`.

Comment: How did you try `long int`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also [I get](https://wandbox.org/permlink/J13QtrTTdrJ8GEH5) `104784`, not `104787`.

Comment: All of the multiplication in the function `Area` has at least one even number as their operands. this means all of the multiplication results will be even, and then the result of addition and subtraction will be even. On the other hand, the expected value `104787` is odd. This looks very strange.

Comment: right, is 104784, my bad

Comment: "*im using turbo C*". That's your real problem. Why use such an old compiler where even the `int` size is different to almost any modern compiler? There are many free compilers out there and using any of those would be better than turbo C.

Comment: @MikeCAT i already figured it out, was a dumb mistake, was still using ```int``` as argument, thanks for replying, may be im just too tired rn

Comment: `-26288` is `0x9950` and `104784` is `0x19950`... OK the calculation is done well and just the result is truncated to fit in the 16-bit `int`.

Comment: @MikeCAT well you clearly know things i dont haha, now, thats interesting

Comment: @kaylum college

Answer (score 1):

the answer was simple, it is because I was still using `int` as arguments, since `int` here was just `16 bits`, the maximum positive number It can represent is given by `2^16 / 2 - 1 = 65,536 / 2 - 1` we divide by 2 cause it also represents negative values and - 1 cause it also represents the number 0 so we get  `65,536 / 2 - 1= 32,767` the result `104784` clearly overflows the maximum positive number It can represent so it truncates to `-26288` to fit `int` data type.

I was kind of tired to notice I was still using int variables as arguments, I already knew this but thanks a lot to @MikeCAT for making me double check so I could realize.

I thought I was using `long int` as arguments for some reason when I wasn't.

```
long int Area(int ax, int ay, int bx, int by, int cx, int cy)
{
    return ax * by - ay * bx + bx * cy - by * cx + cx * ay - cy * ax;
}
```

so `ax * by - ay * bx + bx * cy - by * cx + cx * ay - cy * ax` expression was still being computed as `int`, I just needed to change arguments data type as well. right way:

```
long int Area(long int ax, long int ay, long int bx, long int by, long int cx, long int cy)
{
    return ax * by - ay * bx + bx * cy - by * cx + cx * ay - cy * ax;
}
```